# Representing propagators as Dirac delta functions

Tags: mathematics, regularization, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

I have found online, in particular on the wolfram site, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html,
certain identities that allow one to represent a delta function as limits. Of particular interest to me are the relations:

$$ \delta (x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\epsilon}{x^2 + \epsilon^2} $$

$$\delta (x) = 1/2 \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}  \epsilon |x|^{\epsilon-1}$$

Can anyone tell me where I might find a reference that derives those, and possibly gives a generalization for higher dimensional delta functions.

On a related point, a paper I was reading uses the "textbook formula"

$$ \frac{1}{|x|^{2n+d-\epsilon}} \propto \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\Box^{n} \delta^{(d)}(x)$$
with some constant or proportionality dependent on $n$.

Any information on the said textbook would equally be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the Wolfram page includes some references for those formulas... (as for the generalization to higher dimensions, you only need to consider products of one-dimensional deltas, $\delta(\boldsymbol x)=\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)$)

Comment: 1. This is not a physics question 2. To "derive" those formula, you first need to say with respect to what norm those limits are supposed to be taken on what space. You need to look into functional analysis and the theory of distributions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: This is a question for [math.se], but even then it's much too vague to be answerable. What sort of generalization are you looking for? Are you looking for the Mother Of All Delta Function Formulas? (hint: it doesn't exist.) If not, then what are you looking for?